# ValueError: Maximum allowed size exceeded

Tags: python, 3d

So I'm trying to get some data from a set of equations in the code below. The equations are correct and I've checked them. I'm trying to loop the data over the array set as x in the hopes of scanning or looping across it later, but when I try to run the code I get the ValueError: Maximum allowed size exceeded. The problem appeared when I tried to loop the array of x in reverse. The non-working code is below:

```
from numpy import *


r=1.0 #radius
d=0.01 #separation of lines
L=1.0 #Length
i=0.01
n=1/d #number of lines
b=-r #position of each line with respect to the radial component
xs=[]
ys=[]
zs=[]
while b<=r:
    x=arange(0,L,i) #sets up the x-coordinate system needed for each data point
    for i in x:
        y=0*x+b
        z1=sqrt((r**2)-(y**2)) #plotting the straight lines
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)
        zs.append(z1)
    for i in reversed(x):
        u=d*x+b
        z2=sqrt((r**2)-(u**2)) #plotting the diagonal lines 
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(u)
        zs.append(z2)
    b=b+d
print(xs,ys,zs)
```

And the error I get is:Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('/Users/Alex/Desktop/fibre_data.py', wdir='/Users/Alex/Desktop')

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/Users/Alex/Desktop/fibre_data.py", line 22, in 
    x=arange(0,L,i) #sets up the x-coordinate system needed for each data point

ValueError: Maximum allowed size exceeded

Comment: You have reused the variable `i` multiple times, so when the while loop passes through a second time `i` is zero and the numpy array tries to create a list of infinite (undefined because divide by zero) length.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you